# Bootstrap form formatting not applying

Tags: html, css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add a form for subscription emails with the instance variable @premail in embedded ruby

For some reason the form will not have the bootstrap styling with it when I load it on my localhost. I've tried several things but I can't get the form to look like a bootstrap input form. Here is the code for my form:

```
    <div class="container-form">
            <%= form_for @premail, html: {class: "form-horizontal home-form", role: "form"} do |f| %>
              <% if @premail.errors.any? %>                 
                  <h2><%= pluralize(@premail.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this link from being saved:</h2>
                  <ul>
                  <% @premail.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                  <% end %>
                  </ul>
              <% end %>
              <div class="form-group">
                <p> Stay updated for our launch! </p>
                <%= f.label :email, class:"col-sm-2 control-label" %>
                <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Enter email" %>
              </div>
              <div>
                <%= f.submit "Sign up", class:"btn btn-default" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
      </div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please also supply the outputted HTMl. Also an obvious question but are you loading the bootstrap css correctly?

Comment: Did you include both `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-theme.css` files?

Comment: I am using the @import "bootstrap";  at the top of my stylesheets/application.css.scss file

Comment: That's fine. also you could import `bootstrap-theme.css`

Comment: Hmm well my form still doesn't work. What does that do? Never used it. I'm still learning. I am trying to use the simple form gem now to do it, maybe I'll be able to figure it out..

Comment: I just pasted the form markup code directly from bootstrap and it did not style... I am guessing bootstrap is not being read properly for some reason..